# Importing an XML file into a dataframe

Tags: xml, r

I have an XML file DemoFeed.XML and am trying to get it into a dataframe using the XML package and function xmlToDataFrame. However I am getting an error message:Error: XML content does not seem to be XML, nor to identify a file name

```
 <demo_feed>  
 <TimeStamp>20090610153000</TimeStamp>
 <XAU Bid="952.2" Ask="953.0"/>
 <XAG Bid="15.17" Ask="15.22"/>
 <XPT Bid="1266" Ask="1271"/>
 <XPD Bid="256" Ask="261"/>
 <EUR Bid="1.3993" Ask="1.3996"/>
 </demo_feed>
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Kind regards,

Adam

Comment: How are you calling this function? It expects a filename (or an already-parsed XML document) and the error message says that there is no such file. In addition, it would only retrieve the contents of the nodes, not their attributes: some more work may be needed.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you can probably use the [XML Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html)

Comment: That's not formatted in the clean way xmlToDataFrame expects to get so you would need to use xmlTreeParse instead.

Comment: This works fine in Windows but not on OS X. I think there is a problem accessing the file. An OS problem.

Comment: I got the same error on OS X when I tried to parse a file_url; however, no problem when the doc was downloaded. Example: file_url <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
download.file(file_url,destfile="/data/stuff.xml",method="curl");
doc <- xmlTreeParse("/data/stuff.xml");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hansi's comment is correct. This is one way to do it:

```
> doc = xmlParse('demofeed.xml')
> data.frame(t(xpathSApply(doc, 
      '/demo_feed/*[@Bid]', 
      function(x) c(name=xmlName(x), xmlAttrs(x)))))

  name    Bid    Ask
1  XAU  952.2  953.0
2  XAG  15.17  15.22
3  XPT   1266   1271
4  XPD    256    261
5  EUR 1.3993 1.3996
```